# How I can disable HTTP Transfer-Encoding: chunked in UPNP event notifications?

Tags: http, upnp, transfer-encoding

I have an http server, which listens for UPNP events, and which not support http "Transfer-Encoding: chunked". When I subscribe to the UPNP device service notification, I use http v1.0, but I still receive notifications with HTTP 1.1 and "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"

Comment: I suspect you're dealing with a buggy UPnP device stack (which one(s) are doing this?).  If you control the code running on your target devices, you could change this.  Otherwise, you likely have no choice but to implement support for de-chunking in your control point.

Comment: What simonc says: responding with HTTP/1.1 chunked encoding in response to HTTP/1.0 requests is explicitly forbidden in the spec... Either live with it (i.e. implement chunks) or try to get the other device fixed (this is typically a _Don Quijote_ moment).

Comment: Buggy device is the Microsoft Windows Media Player Sharing device.